# React Native Fetch JSON = url empty

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I'm developing an App (very simple App), that request a JSON API. The piece of code that makes me angry is :

```
fetch("http://xxx/api/v1/samples", {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + userToken
  }
}).then((response) => {
  if (response.ok) {
    return response.json();
  }

  throw new Error('error');
}).then((samples) => {
  console.log(samples);
  this.setState({
    data: samples,
    error: samples.error || null,
    loading: false,
    refreshing: false
  });
}).catch((error) => {
  AlertIOS.alert("OOPS", error.message);
});
```

The API returns:

```
{
  "code": "4345",
  "id": 3,
  "comment": "Echantillon trouvé dans un étang",
  "updated_at": {
    "date": "2017-07-04 11:04:34.000000",
    "timezone_type": 3,
    "timezone": "Europe/Zurich"
  },
  "project_name": "Récolte de Lézards",
  "thumbs": "http://xxx/storage-app-uploads-public-595-e01-893-595e01893c826572100952-8cf6abfd3440f538dfa95b1d581b7487.png",
  "pictures": [
    "http://xxx/storage-app-uploads-public-595-e01-893-595e01893c826572100952-8cf6abfd3440f538dfa95b1d581b7487.png"
  ]
}
```

**My problem**
The var "samples" is correct (contains all fields; id, code, comment, …) expect that all the urls are empty strings.

The result of a `console.log(samples)` just before `this.setState`:

`{
      "code": "4345",
      "id": 3,
      "comment": "Echantillon trouvé dans un étang",
      "updated_at": {
        "date": "2017-07-04 11:04:34.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "Europe/Zurich"
      },
      "project_name": "Récolte de Lézards",
      "thumbs": "",
      "pictures": [
        ""
      ]
    }`

Cannot find out why.

Any ideas? Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What are you doing with `this.state.data` after doing your `fetch`?

Comment: Why do you `throw` at `.then()`? Is `alert()` called? What is expected result?

Comment: @MichaelCheng: For now, I do not anything with this.state.data (because it does not work…).

Comment: @guest271314: Forget the throw; if removed, it is the same. I want, in "samples", to have "thumbs" and "pictures" with the same values as from the API request… Alert is not called.

Comment: @GregoryLoichot Ok, maybe I'm misunderstanding something. You're saying `samples` when inspected has the JSON you included in the question. However, `this.state.data` when inspected has the same JSON but `thumbs` and `pictures` are empty strings? I'm trying to figure out how you are checking that the JSON has empty url strings after doing the `setState`. Just trying to reproduce the issue since there's not enough information at the moment to do so.

Comment: Is expected result an `Array`?

Comment: What do you expect `this` to be within `.then()`?

Comment: I expect `samples.thumbs` and `samples.pictures` to be the same as in the API request (I had a `console.log`).

Comment: try `https` url

Comment: What does `console.log(this)` within `.then((samples) =>{})` log?

Answer (score 0):

`samples` is a JavaScript plain object. If expected result is an `Array` defined at `"data"` property of object passed to `.setState()`, set `samples.pictures` and `.concat()`  `samples.thumbs` at `"data"` property.

Remove `throw` from `.then()` chained to `fetch()` call to avoid unexpected result.

```
data: samples.pictures.concat(samples.thumbs)
```

Comment: Ok, I added a console.log to explain. samples.thumbs is empty, but the API returns a value, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @YaSH, you are right. With HTTPS url, the strings are not empty… But why… I did not find any mentions of that point in the documentation…

@guest271314: this is equal to the component in which the fetch is called.